# Different ways of showing SP list results?

Tags: 2013

I apologize if this question has already been asked and answered. I'm pretty new to the SP world and I've found that looking up solutions is super hard when you don't really know what you're searching for.

Anyways, I've created a list with a lookup field connected to a separate list with objects to choose from a separate list. My problem is that when multiple objects are listed, the objects are all within one cell of each column making it very difficult to discern what info within each column goes with info inside the other columns. Preferrably the objects would be listed each on their own rows if possible.

Is there a solution out there that would work for me?

Oh, Im running this on sharepoint 2013.

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say you are on SP 2013, I would say this sounds like a good candidate for some custom Client Side Rendering (CSR).

CSR is a system SP 2013 uses to render the data in the browser, both for general list views (such as in your screen shot), and also on the Display and Edit forms for the individual items.  Thankfully, the way the CSR system was designed, Microsoft provided an easy way for you to hook into the system and override the default rendering with your own custom rendering.

You could use that to render your multiple items in each cell in a little table or something, so that the information is lining up more to your liking.

Here is an [excellent article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) to get you started, but if you just search the web for "SharePoint CSR" you will find plenty of other examples and information.

(And, just as a pedantic aside: you will also see many people referring to CSR as "JSLink".  They are not the same thing.  The reason for the confusion is that JSLink and CSR go hand in hand - JSLink is a very convenient way to get javascript files to load, and in that regard, you often use JSLink to load the javascript files necessary to do your CSR overrides.  But you do not necessarily need JSLink to load CSR overrides, and conversely you can load non-CSR related javascript using JSLink.)

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the help, ill get right on it!